# Launching a workflow in Apache Hop Server using REST APIs

Tags: rest, apache-hop

I'm trying to launch an Apache Hop Worfklow using REST APIs, but I can't find the right way to do it.

I setup a docker container with Apache Hop Server (image apache/hop:2.6.0) and I mounted the project home inside /files/test. In the project home I have these files:

- metadata (this is the metadata dir of the project)
- create_rows.hpl (this is a test pipeline)
- main.hwf (this is the test workflow)
- project-config.json

I passed these environment variables to the process:

- HOP_PROJECT_NAME: "test-docker"
- HOP_PROJECT_FOLDER: "/files/test"

Then I tried to execute the "main.hwf" from the REST API of the Apache Hop server. I tried using "http://localhost:8180/hop/startWorkflow?name=main", "http://localhost:8180/hop/startWorkflow?name=main.hwf", and "http://localhost:8180/hop/startWorkflow?name=/files/test/main.hwf" but I always get the error "The specified workflow [main] could not be found" (obviously, the name of the workflow in the error changes according to the parameter "name" I use).

What's the correct way to start a workflow using the REST API?

I'm trying to setup a container with all the files needed (pipelines and workflows) already loaded, so I hope I don't need to manually upload the project to the running server.